# how to connect automatically to a saved list of networks

Tags: shell-script, wifi

I want to make my Debian laptop connect automatically to a list of stored WiFi networks in a text file that have the syntax **SSID:password**, using a non graphical way (script or config).

These networks could have different types of security: Open, Wep, WPA or WPA2

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the commands you would use to manually connect to those networks. Can you store the list of network names along with their security and needed keys  in a text file?

Comment: yes i would like to save the SSID:Pass paires in a text file

Comment: OK. Please _[edit]_ your question and include an example of this text file and the commands you use to connect to your networks.

Comment: there are many solutions to connect to a wifi network depending on the Security type. i am looking for a good way to connect to these wifi access points using one script

Comment: i use tutorials, that need many steps of configuration, and only allow me to connect one SSID

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include some of these commands. The details will depend on your machine (e.g. the name of your wireless card). Once we have them, writing a shell loop that reads through a list of networks and passwords and tries them until it manages to connect to one is very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that i) your wireless interface is called `wlan0` and ii) you have already connected to these networks at least once, so that their credentials are saved and iii) that you're using [NetworkManager](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager) (you probably are); you could use [`nmcl`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=1&query=nmcli&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en), NetworkManager's commandline interface.

Create a text file with the list of network names you want to try:

```
network1
network2
network3
```

Then, iterate over that file, attempting to connect:

```
while read essid; do nmcli con up id "$essid" && break; done < list.txt
```

That will attempt to connect to each of the ESSIDs in the file and stop as soon as a connection is established.

---

If your networks' security credentials are not saved, you can create a list that has both the ESSID and the required key:

```
network1 key1
network2 key2
network3 key3
```

Then, iterate over those values and use `iwconfig` to connect:

```
while read essid key; do
    sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "$essid" key s:"$key"
done < list.txt
```

Note that the above is being run with `sudo`. This means that you can't fully automate it unless you run it as `root`.